# How should I set net core api cors?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, content-security-policy

I am coding an unofficial twitter api for myself. Then I send a get to this api using the console screen in my browser with the following method.

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

such

```
httpGet(https://localhost:44311/WeatherForecast/alienationxs/true);
```

the problem is that when i do this via [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it's ok and json data reaches me. but when I do it via twitter.com I get the following error.

[image]

via google.com

[image]

my cors settings on api

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCors(options =>
      options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
      builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin())); ;
           
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "twitterAPI", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
           
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "twitterAPI v1"));
            }

           
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(builder => builder
             .AllowAnyOrigin()
             .AllowAnyMethod()
             .AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

all i want is to reach my api via twitter.com just like google.com.

Comment: if you can connect google.com, you should make sure this twitter api can be reached first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, let's separate the flies from the cutlets.

- Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) - is a separate security layer.
- Content Security Policy (CSP) - is a separate security layer, it's appied before CORS. After passing through CSP yous can face with CORS if last one is breached.

As you can see from error message "*... because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive ...*", you faced with CSP violation therefore your CORS settings have no mean.

2. What's goin on.

You enter `twitter.com` web page and tries to execute connect request to `localhost:44311` on behalf of twitter web page. But twitter's web page protected by CSP which forbid such requests:
[image]
Pay attention on 'connect-src' directive, which governs XMLHttpRequest().

The `www.google.com` web page does not have CSP, therefore you request on behalf of google does success.

Comment: So is there any way to get around this?

Comment: No way. Bypass CSP in Chrome costs [$20,000](https://www.google.com/about/appsecurity/chrome-rewards/#rewards) under Bug Bounty program.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API does not support CORS.

Comment: Scraping Twitter is against the Terms of Service. I'll remove the twitter tag from your post, since you're asking about a generic web programming issue, not about Twitter.